# Can't Center middle textview when makeing app for my HTC

Tags: android, eclipse, textview, center, html-table

For about 3 week ago I started looking for the first time in to this program Eclipse and the possibility to make my own app for my HTC. I'm playing Modern Warefare 3 on PC and I like to keep track on my statistics when playing. I made an application in VisualBasic that extracts my stats and uploads it to my site. From there I download the stats to my HTC. Everything works perfect, but I can't get the yellow XP to center in the textvew.

[image: http://mw3.decoy.se/mw3.png]

I have google for a solution, but i have not find any with my specific problem.

Here is the code from main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
    android:stretchColumns="0,2"
    android:shrinkColumns="1">

        <TableRow 
            android:background="#363B38" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/gamename"
                android:textColor ="#FCCA65" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:background="#FF2E3230" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <TextView

                android:layout_span="3"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/gamerank"/>
        </TableRow> 


        <TableRow

            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#FF2E3230">

            <TextView
                android:text="00"
                android:id="@+id/gamelevelc" 
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="00 / 00 XP"
                android:id="@+id/gamexp"
                android:textColor="#FEFC41"                 
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="00" 
                android:id="@+id/gameleveln" 
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>
        </TableRow>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/myProgress"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:max="100" />

        <TableRow android:background="#FF2E3230">
            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/score" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:id="@+id/gamescore"
                android:textColor ="#D2AD53" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FF363B38">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/wins" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gamewins"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FF2E3230">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/losses" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gamelosses"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FF363B38">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/ties" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gameties"
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>
        </TableRow>         
        <TableRow android:background="#FF2E3230">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/win_streak" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gamewinstreak"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FF363B38">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/kills" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gamekills"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor ="#D2AD53" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FF2E3230">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/deaths" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gamedeaths"
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FF363B38">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/kd_ratio" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gameratio"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </TableRow>         
        <TableRow android:background="#FF2E3230">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/headshots" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gameheadshots"
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>
        </TableRow>


                <TableRow android:background="#FF363B38">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/hits" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gamehits"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FF2E3230">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/misses" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gamemisses"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:background="#FF363B38">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/accuracy" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gamepercent"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FF2E3230">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/assists" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gameassists"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:background="#FF363B38">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/kill_streak" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gamekillstreak"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </TableRow> 
        <TableRow android:background="#FF2E3230">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/time_played" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gametimeplayed"
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>
        </TableRow> 
        <View        
        android:layout_height="3dip"        
        android:background="#FF000000" />   
        <TableRow android:background="#FF363B38">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/games_played" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gameplayed"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </TableRow> 

        <TableRow android:background="#FF2E3230">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/latest_game" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gamelastplayed"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </TableRow>     

        <TableRow android:background="#54604A">

            <TextView
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/updated_at" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gamelastupdated"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </TableRow>                 
    </TableLayout>
```

Any suggestions? I'm new at Eclipse and makeing apps for android, so please no advanced programing suggestions :-)

Regards
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `android:layout_weight` attribute for your `TextView`s. Specify `android:layout_width="0dip"` for every of them and set `android:layout_weight="1"`. This will make every of your three `TextView`s occupy 1/3 of the screens width. Now you can change `android:gravity` attribute for every `TextView` to change the text positioning in its 1/3 of the screen. For example, use `center` to center the text, or `left` to bind it to the left side of its bounding rectangle. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.. this was the solution, but i need to set weight="7", could set it to a lower number but between 4-7, because with just 1 on all three causing a wordwrap on the center field. The left and right value length will never be more then 2 digits.

Comment: @George, Then you can set the center View's weight to 2 or more and it will occupy more place.

Comment: Changed 7 to 2 as you suggested, and it worked perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: @George, Glad it's helped! Please consider accepting the answer if you've found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

change to this and give a try:

```
<TextView
android:text="00 / 00 XP"
android:id="@+id/gamexp"
android:textColor="#FEFC41"
android:layout_gravity="center"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: Did try this first, but there was no change in layout, but thanks anyway.